# Do I need Express or some other framework in order to make a Node site?

Tags: node.js

People keep mentioning Node as a back-end framework but it's actually a runtime. Does this mean I need to install a package like Express in order to actually create a website based on the Node runtime? Does Node come with its' own implementation of a back-end framework?

Looking at [the Node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/) most of this stuff has nothing to do with usual framework stuff like testing, migrations, MVC, or asset precompilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not *required* to use Express or a similar framework to develop web pages since you can just create a web server using Node's [http module](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html).

That being said, the additional functionality that a framework like Express would provide is something you should at least consider.

Comment: Are you saying the HTTP Module is just enough to make a website, but it's nothing compared to a real framework? Thank you for explaining this!

Comment: Well, it's just a basic module that helps you start the web server. You'll still need to handle your own routing and so on. Of course, you can use routing modules but then you're getting closer to Express since it provides them.

Comment: Not to mention how much work that would take to implement when Express has it already!